# Can the instructions in a thread change during execution? (OS)

Tags: operating-system

I'm currently researching threads in the context of the operating system and I'm unsure if a thread is a set sequence of instructions that can be repeatedly executed or if it is filled and replaced with new instructions by the user or the operating system.

Thanks a bundle!
-Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean - the compiled instructions for a program are stored in memory and are not changed at runtime (at least for languages which are not JIT-compiled).

A thread is an entirely separate concept from the code itself. A thread gives you the ability to be running at "two places at once" in the code. At a conceptual level, a thread is simply a container for the context that you need at any point in the execution of some code. This means that each thread has a call stack and a set of registers (which are either actually stored in the registers of a processor if the thread is running, or elsewhere if the thread is paused).

Almost all thread libraries work such that a new thread will execute some user-defined function and will then exit. This function can be long-running, just like `main()` (which is the function executed by the first thread in your process).

If the threads are supported by the OS (ie they are not "green threads"/"fibers") they will exit by calling an OS API which tells the OS it can deallocate any data it has which is associated with that thread.

Sometimes, abstractions are built on top of this mechanism such that a thread or pool of threads will execute a function which simply loops over a queue of tasks to run, but the fundamental mechanism is the same. However, these abstractions are provided by user libraries built on top of the OS threading mechanisms, not by the OS itself.